# PDO Transaction + Prepare, undefined parameter

Tags: php, pdo

I can't find the error here:

```
  function updateDocKeywords($keywords, $docId) {
    try {
      $query = 'UPDATE keywords SET :keyname = :keyvalue WHERE document_id = :docId';
      $pdo = _openConnection();
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $pdo->beginTransaction();
      $pdoStatement = $pdo->prepare($query);
      foreach($keywords as $keyname=>$keyval) {
        var_dump($keyname,$keyval,$docId);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':docId', $docId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':keyname', $keyname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':keyval', $keyval, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdoStatement->execute();
      }
      $pdo->commit();
      return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      $pdo->rollBack();
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

In the browser I'm getting:

```
string(5) "Fecha"
string(8) "20141122"
string(4) "5233"
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

And in the exception handler, PHPStorms warns me that `$pdo` might not been defined, which is another question, why would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this,

```
:keyval

$pdoStatement->bindParam(':keyvalue', $keyval, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

into

```
:keyvalue
```

Comment: Agggrrr, I swear I watched it again and again and didn't find it. If PDO just told me what variable was I would have saved 1 hour.